# quickxml with serde: how to parse list of different XML elements?

Tags: xml, rust, serde

I am trying to parse Eclipse launch configuration. It is basically a dictionary of properties, where element names represent different property types:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.localJavaApplication">
    <listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_PATHS">
        <listEntry value="/example/src/main/java/com/example/MyMain.java"/>
    </listAttribute>
    <listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_TYPES">
        <listEntry value="1"/>
    </listAttribute>
    <listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.ui.favoriteGroups">
        <listEntry value="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchGroup.debug"/>
        <listEntry value="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchGroup.run"/>
    </listAttribute>
    <booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.ATTR_USE_START_ON_FIRST_THREAD" value="true"/>
    <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_PROVIDER" value="org.eclipse.m2e.launchconfig.classpathProvider"/>
    <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.MAIN_TYPE" value="com.example.MyMain"/>
    <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROJECT_ATTR" value="datastore.tas"/>
    <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.SOURCE_PATH_PROVIDER" value="org.eclipse.m2e.launchconfig.sourcepathProvider"/>
    <stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.VM_ARGUMENTS" value="-Dspring.profiles.include=dev&#13;&#10;-Xmx1g"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

With `quick_xml` code it's easy to create serde-annotated structs that can generate correct XML for this; however, I am unable to parse the XML with the same structs.

How can this be accomplished?

Here is my code:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct EclipseLaunchConfiguration {
    #[serde(rename = "@type")]
    configuration_type: String,
    #[serde(default)]
    attrs: Vec<ConfigAttribute>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
enum ConfigAttribute {
    #[serde(rename = "booleanAttribute")]
    Bool {
        #[serde(rename = "@key")]
        key: String,
        #[serde(rename = "@value")]
        value: bool,
    },
    #[serde(rename = "stringAttribute")]
    Str {
        #[serde(rename = "@key")]
        key: String,
        #[serde(rename = "@value")]
        value: String,
    },
    #[serde(rename = "listAttribute")]
    List{
        #[serde(rename = "@key")]
        key: String,
        #[serde(rename = "listEntry")]
        list_entry: Vec<ListEntry>,
    },
    #[serde(rename = "mapAttribute")]
    Map{
        #[serde(rename = "@key")]
        key: String,
        #[serde(rename = "listEntry")]
        map_entry: Vec<MapEntry>,
    },
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "snake_case")]
struct ListEntry {
    #[serde(rename = "@value")]
    value: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "snake_case")]
struct MapEntry {
    #[serde(rename = "@key")]
    key: String,
    #[serde(rename = "@value")]
    value: String,
}

#[cfg(test)] mod tests {

    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_to_xml() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
        let config = EclipseLaunchConfiguration {
            configuration_type: "whatever".to_string(),
            attrs: vec![
                ConfigAttribute::Bool{
                    key: "ok".to_string(),
                    value: true,
                },
                ConfigAttribute::Str {
                    key: "hello".to_string(),
                    value: "world".to_string(),
                },
                ConfigAttribute::List{
                    key: "list".to_string(),
                    list_entry: vec![
                        ListEntry {
                            value: "one".to_string(),
                        },
                        ListEntry {
                            value: "two".to_string(),
                        },
                    ],
                },
                ConfigAttribute::Map {
                    key: "map".to_string(),
                    map_entry: vec![
                        MapEntry {
                            key: "one".to_string(),
                            value: "1".to_string(),
                        },
                        MapEntry {
                            key: "two".to_string(),
                            value: "2".to_string(),
                        },
                    ],
                }
            ],
        };
        let xml = quick_xml::se::to_string(&config)?;
        println!("{}", xml);
        let config2: EclipseLaunchConfiguration = quick_xml::de::from_str(&xml)?;
        println!("{:#?}", config2);
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

The provided test prints this output:

```
<EclipseLaunchConfiguration type="whatever"><booleanAttribute key="ok" value="true"/><stringAttribute key="hello" value="world"/><listAttribute key="list"><listEntry value="one"/><listEntry value="two"/></listAttribute><mapAttribute key="map"><listEntry key="one" value="1"/><listEntry key="two" value="2"/></mapAttribute></EclipseLaunchConfiguration>
EclipseLaunchConfiguration {
    configuration_type: "whatever",
    attrs: [],
}
```

which proves that serde annotations are good enough for serialization but not for deserialization.

Comment: Usually this issue is due to namespaces not being defined in the deserialize methods. Compare you serialized xml against the original xml and look for differences. Deserialize should work once the serialized xml matches the original xml file.

Comment: do you mean XML namespaces? there are none

Comment: @jdweng OP is trying to re-deserialize XML they just serialized. Doesn't that mean they already match?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work, but I found it via trial and error, so I can provide little insight as to why (the [docs](https://docs.rs/quick-xml/0.30.0/quick_xml/de/index.html#value) may provide some insight):

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct EclipseLaunchConfiguration {
    #[serde(rename = "@type")]
    configuration_type: String,
    #[serde(default, rename = "$value")]
    attrs: Vec<ConfigAttribute>,
}
```